# VBA Autheticate to SharePoint Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, office, vba

I tried to follow the base instructions using this post (as it was the only one I could find) http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2016/03/21/step-by-step-sharepoint-online-authentiaction-process-via-http-protocol/#comment-47401

however when I get to Step 4 I do get a response but it does not contain "STSAuth" it only returns

State: 4, Login: username@,NameSpaceType: Managed, DomainName: ,FederationBrandName: , CloudInstanceName: microsoftonline.com, CloudInstanceIssuerUri: urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline, IsFederatedNSSuccess: "true

So I don't know how to continue the authentication.
I am using VBA from Excel to issue the calls

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: Thankyou I'll take a look.

Comment: If you could provide a definitive start to end authentication that would be awesome.  I'd tenant the url of my base sharepoint?.

Comment: I tend to.use Json.  Is there a way of showing that in your code requests rather than http

Comment: Thank you for your response appreciated finding o365 frustrating.  I have a lot of vba code written for on premises that has been working for so long. I'm also having problems with authenticating to jira.  Any assistance there would also be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check the VBA code as below.

```
Private Function GetO365SPO_SAMLAssertionIntegrated() As String
    Dim CustomStsUrl As String, CustomStsSAMLRequest, stsMessage As String

    CustomStsUrl = "https://sts.<tenant>.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport"
    CustomStsSAMLRequest = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:a=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">" & _
            "<s:Heade>" & _
                "<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=""1"">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>" & _
                "<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:[[messageID]]</a:MessageID>" & _
                "<a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous;</a:Address>;</a:ReplyTo>" & _
                "<a:To s:mustUnderstand=""1"">[[mustUnderstand]];</a:To>" & _
            "</s:Header>"
    CustomStsSAMLRequest = CustomStsSAMLRequest & _
            "<s:Body>" & _
                "<t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"">" & _
                    "<wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"">" & _
                        "<wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">" & _
                        "<wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</wsa:Address>;</wsa:EndpointReference>" & _
                    "</wsp:AppliesTo>" & _
                    "<t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey;</t:KeyType>" & _
                    "<t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue;</t:RequestType>" & _
                "</t:RequestSecurityToken>" & _
            "</s:Body>" & _
        "</s:Envelope>"


    stsMessage = Replace(CustomStsSAMLRequest, "[[messageID]]", Mid(O365SPO_CreateGuidString(), 2, 36))
    stsMessage = Replace(stsMessage, "[[mustUnderstand]]", CustomStsUrl)

    ' Create HTTP Object ==> make sure to use "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" iso "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"; as the latter does not send the NTLM
    ' credentials as Authorization header.
    Dim Request As Object
    Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Get SAML:assertion
    Request.Open "POST", CustomStsUrl, False
    Request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    Request.send (stsMessage)

    If Request.Status = 200 Then
         GetO365SPO_SAMLAssertionIntegrated = O365SPO_ExtractXmlNode(Request.responseText, "saml:Assertion", False)
    End If

End Function

Private Function O365SPO_ExtractXmlNode(xml As String, name As String, valueOnly As Boolean) As String
    Dim nodeValue As String
    nodeValue = Mid(xml, InStr(xml, "<" & name))
    If valueOnly Then
        nodeValue = Mid(nodeValue, InStr(nodeValue, ">") + 1)
        O365SPO_ExtractXmlNode = Left(nodeValue, InStr(nodeValue, "</" & name) - 1)
    Else
        O365SPO_ExtractXmlNode = Left(nodeValue, InStr(nodeValue, "lt;/" & name) + Len(name) + 2)
    End If
End Function

Private Function O365SPO_CreateGuidString()
    Dim guid As GUID_TYPE
    Dim strGuid As String
    Dim retValue As LongPtr
    Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

    retValue = CoCreateGuid(guid)
    If retValue = 0 Then
        strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
        retValue = StringFromGUID2(guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)
        If retValue = guidLength Then
            ' valid GUID as a string
            O365SPO_CreateGuidString = strGuid
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

More information is here:

[Peculiarity with Active Authentication issues from VBA](https://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2018/04/peculiarity-with-active-authentication.html)

And check the following articles.

[SOAP Only Authentication Using VBA](https://jlattimer.blogspot.sg/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-vba.html)

[Remote authentication in SharePoint Online](https://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/)